# trouble with indexing and printing proper values on a 2-d list python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a simple 2-D list containing x,y pairs. I am making a program to find the two set of points with the shortest distance between them.

The list 'values' contains all of the distances, and I'm pretty sure that they are the right distances.

I want to print out the two points which created the minimum distance. It is obviously very easy to print out the minimum distance, yet printing out the two points is giving me trouble.

I need to keep track of which sets of points are creating which distances.

I think that I will probably have to re-write this code and start fresh in order to accomplish what I want. However, is there anyway to achieve this result with what I have? If not, how do I do this? How do I keep track of what index is being used?

code:

```
multiD = [[1,3],
[-1,-1],
[1,1],
[2,0.5],
[2,-1],
[3,3],
[4,2],
[4,-0.5]]

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    distance = ( (((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1))) ** 0.5)
    return distance

values = []
for [x1,y1] in multiD:
    for [x2,y2] in multiD:
        if [x1,y1] != [x2,y2]:
            diff = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            values.append(diff)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import combinations

points = [
    [ 1,   3],   [-1, -1],   [ 1,  1],
    [ 2, 0.5],   [ 2, -1],   [ 3,  3],
    [ 4,   2],   [ 4, -0.5]
]

def dist(pair):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = pair
    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5

def main():
    pairs = combinations(points, 2)
    closest = min(pairs, key=dist)
    print("The closest pair is {} at {}.".format(closest, dist(closest)))

if __name__=="__main_":
    main()
```

produces

```
The closest pair is ([1, 1], [2, 0.5]) at 1.118033988749895.
```

Comment: if you have the time, what exactly is the key doing? when it is taken out, we get a different set of pairs. Is it just telling closest that the minimum in pairs must come from the distance function? I'm not sure

Comment: It says "find the minimum set of pairs as judged by distance". If you remove `key=dist`, you get "find the minimum set of pairs as judged by ascending numeric order", which would be `([-1, -1], [1, 1])`.